# hidden or alternative fo:table-footer on last page with XSL-FO / Apache FOP

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to generate a dynamic pdf with [apache fop](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) containing a multipage [`fo:table`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_table). How is it possible to hide a [`fo:table-footer`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_table-footer) or set an alternative table-footer on the last page?

There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374508/xsl-fo-footer-on-last-page) for different *page* footers using [`fo:static-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_static-content) and [`fo:conditional-page-master-reference`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_conditional-page-master-reference). But I think, this is not the right direction to search - or is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `table-omit-footer-at-break="true"` on your `fo:table` so you  don't get the footer until the end of the table.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#table-omit-footer-at-break

Otherwise, you could use an `fo:marker` to get your content in the footer of the last page that the table is on.

Comment: fo:marker did it, a detailed solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974903/xslfo-retrieve-marker-not-valid-child/31012095#31012095